# Como obtener los elementos de un array en un loop for

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

Estoy aprendiendo JavaScript. Estoy intentando mostrar los elementos de un array en un loop (estoy colocando preguntas y cuando hago click en una flecha los va a ir cambiando).
Mi código es así:

`let categoriaVideoJuegos = [
    "Cuál es el orden de los videojuegos Borderlands",
    "En qué año salió Quake 1",
    "En qué año salió Quake 2",
    "En qué año salió Quake 3",
]`

```
const mostrarPreguntas = function() {
    let tituloPregunta = document.getElementsByClassName("titulo-pregunta");

    for (i = 0; i < categoriaVideoJuegos.length; i++) {
        tituloPregunta[0].innerHTML = categoriaVideoJuegos[i];
    }

}
```

El problema es que estoy únicamente recibiendo el último elemento siempre.

Comment: quieres que la primera vez obtener la pregunta 1, la segunda vez la pregunta 2 y asi sucesivamente?

Comment: Exacto :) Más abajo me dijeron de agregar += pero eso solo me suma los elementos y no quiero eso, quiero que aparezca uno por vez.

Comment: Hola @Nicthema. Creo que deberías explicar un poco mejor lo que deseas obtener. Estoy viendo diversas personas interpretar las cosas de diferente forma. Intenta explicar lo que deseas hacer, o poner una foto de muestra de lo que te gustaría conseguir. Puedes usar el botón editar de debajo de tu pregunta. ¿A que te refieres con una flecha?

Answer (score 1):

Te muestra el último elemento porque lo sobre-escribe en la vista, debes agregar un `+` antes del `=` para que se concatene los valores del array.

```js
let categoriaVideoJuegos = [
    "Cuál es el orden de los videojuegos Borderlands",
    "En qué año salió Quake 1",
    "En qué año salió Quake 2",
    "En qué año salió Quake 3",
]

const mostrarPreguntas = function() {
    let tituloPregunta = document.getElementsByClassName("titulo-pregunta");

    for (i = 0; i < categoriaVideoJuegos.length; i++) {

           tituloPreguntas[0].innerHTML += categoriaVideoJuegos[i];
    }

}
```

Ejemplo

```js
let peliculas = ['Batman','Superman','Aquaman'];

let contenedor = document.getElementById('contenedor');

for(let i = 0; i < peliculas.length; i++){
setTimeout(function(){
            
     contenedor.innerText += peliculas[i]+'\n';
    

       }, 2000);
 }
```

```html
<div id="contenedor"></div>
```

Comment: El tema es que no quiero que se vayan sumando las preguntas, sino que cada elemento del array, es decir cada pregunta, aparezca una por una.

Answer (score 0):

Te muestra siempre el ultimo porque el for se ejecuta demasiado rápido, y por lo que leí lo que buscas hacer es mostrar la primera pregunta y después de unos segundos la segunda y así sucesivamente no?
Puedes implementar un setTimeOut. Por ejemplo

```
for (i = 0; i < categoriaVideoJuegos.length; i++) 
{
  setTimeout(() => 
  {
    tituloPregunta[0].innerHTML = categoriaVideoJuegos[i];
  }, 2000);
}
```